# Ant email IOException

Tags: email, ant, jakarta-mail

I am getting an unhelpful error after trying to complete a ant mail task. Here is the code in question:

```
<mail mailhost="smtp.gmail.com" user="blah" password="blahblah" enableStartTLS="true" subject="jMeter test results from nightly build.">
<from address="me@from.com"/>
<to address="me@me.com"/>
<message>This is an automated message containing results from the most recent discovery build.</message>
<attachments>
    <fileset dir="${basedir}">
        <include name="JMeter-Results*"/>
    </fileset>
</attachments>
</mail>
```

And this is the error:

```
[jmeter] Tidying up remote @ Wed Jun 27 07:40:08 MDT 2012 (1340804408618)
[jmeter] ... end of run
 [xslt] Processing C:\ant-Jmeter\Needed Files\JMeterResults.jtl to C:\ant-Jmeter\Needed Files\JMeter-Results.html
 [xslt] Loading stylesheet C:\ant-Jmeter\Needed Files\jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl
 [mail] Sending email: jMeter test results from nightly build.
 [mail] Failed to send email: IOException while sending message

BUILD FAILED
C:\ant-Jmeter\Needed Files\build.xml:22: Problem while sending mime mail:
Total time: 5 minutes 24 seconds
```

This used to work in the past, but I left it alone for several weeks and now it isn't working. Any Ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

No idea.  There might be a way to turn on JavaMail session debugging for the ant task, which might give you a clue as to what's going wrong, or at least help you figure out if it's an ant problem or a mail sending problem.